# What is this three pin, cyclindrical component?

Tags: components

I'm curious as to what the component is on this PCB. It is surrounded by a polyfuse / zener arrangement (for overvolt / fusing) - I believe it is something to do with the AC input but am not completely sure. It appears to be polarized.

What is it and what might it be used for?

[image: A the bottom of the image is a three pin cylindrical device..]

Comment: Take a picture of the bottom of the PCB and somewhat wider angle as well, top and bottom.  The surrounding components and text can give great clues but only if you show us.  Shaped like an inductor but who knows, consumer gear may have a schematic in the wild but we need a model number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an unshielded inductor of some sort, wound on a ferrite spool and covered with heat shrink tubing.

It may be a simple inductor, perhaps with the middle lead used to stabilize it mechanically or it may be a tapped inductor.

Comment: Your assesment is sound.  I have seen small flash lamp trigger transformers looking a lot like this, though the third terminal was often at the other end.  Perhaps a tapped inductor for a very simple standby power supply.